# Notifications wont show android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-8.0-oreo, android-9.0-pie, android-8.1-oreo

Im trying to get a notification when pressing a button, but it is not showing up. I have followed a lot of tutorials and  i think it has something ti do with the version of android. Something with channels. I just dont know how to implement it.

```
package com.example.root.savetheworldv2;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent =new Intent();
                        PendingIntent pIntent = 
PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this,0,intent,0);
                        Notification noti = new 
Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                                .setTicker("TickerTitle")
                                .setContentTitle("Content Title")
                                .setContentText("Content Text")

.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)

.setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();

                        noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                        NotificationManager nm = 
(NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        nm.notify(0,noti);
```

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels#CreateChannel

Comment: @leonardkraemer but how should i implement it. I am not that good with code.

Comment: There is a code example there. Please try to understand it and then come back if you have a concrete problem or question. SO is not a code writing service.